# croire + adjective (adjective / noun phrase inversion)

Tags: grammaire

Is following the verb *croire* with an adjective acceptable in modern standard French? If so, can anyone specify what kind of verbs have similar valency?

> *Notre âme, notre esprit, notre corps, ont des exigences le plus souvent contradictoires; **je crois malaisé** de joindre des satisfactions si diverses ...*

(I couldn't see anything in le TLF to suggest that it was standard French. In case it's relevant, I should mention that the author - Marguerite Yourcenar - is Belgian.)

NOTE: LPH’s response has reminded me of the class of verbs that can take an adjective as a subject complement (être, devenir, apparaître, paraître, sembler, demeurer, rester). The form then is:

> Subject + copula verb + adjective (+ possible complement of the adjective)

My interest concerns a different construction:

> Subject + non-copula verb + adjective + noun phrase

Comment: Saint-Jacques: The exact construction! Sorry, I didn't spot it, and thank you for checking.

Comment: re: "Croire + adj. + de + inf" at [_croire_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/croire); you're welcome. It's not always easy because of the formatting and abbreviations and such. See also the last item of the entry, _croire + de_, based on the aforementioned. Thanks!

Comment: About *is Belgian*: Marguerite Yourcenar, the first woman to enter the Académie Française, was born in Belgium but as a French citizen. She was raised in France, in the Nord *département* then in Paris. There are no specific belgicisms in her work, outside intentional ones when the action occurs in Belgium .

Comment: @jlliagre: I didn't know that. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette construction est bien du français standard, mais il existe un problème de définition de l'étendue du principe et ce n'est qu'une construction en concurrence avec d'autres ; dans l'ensemble, l'usage se révèle assez hétéroclite.

**A/**  Avec certains verbes cette construction n'est pas possible. Elle est apparemment possible pour certains verbes qui expriment une opinion, un jugement, une apparence…

- croire, tenir (pour), juger, sembler, avoir l'air,…

> Il semble (être) possible de comprendre cela sans étude préliminaire.
>   Le liquide semble coloré.
>   Nous  tenons pour vraies les déclarations confirmées par deux témoins.
>   Ils ont été jugés inaptes à gouverner.
>   Ces alpinistes ont jugé impossible une escalade dans les limites de temps imposées.
>   Elle a l'air neuve ; c'est une voiture très rapide ?

**B/** Pour d'autres verbes on doit interposer  l'adverbe **« comme » suivi de « étant »**<sup>1</sup>.

- considérer, regarder, noter, présenter, ressentir, apparaitre, découler, définir, signaler, dépeindre, marquer, répertorier, …

> Nous concevons comme étant réalisable avant deux années une nouvelle ligne de métro.
>   Ces locutions sont notées comme étant vieilles.

**Note** considérer (comme) impossible ; considéré comme infini ; « considérer infini » ne se dit probablement pas du tout ; « considérer comme remarquable », « considérer remarquable » ne se dit pas ou pratiquement pas.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>La source à partir de laquelle ces verbes sont, je le crois, suffisamment justifiés, est l'[ATILF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/);  elle fournit de nombreux autres verbes qui répondent à ce schéma ; il semble impossible d'obtenir un lien pour ce petit corpus et j'indique donc les étapes de sa constitution au cas que vous ne seriez pas familier avec cette particularité du TLFi ; de la même façon que vous tapez un mot dans le cadre de recherche pour obtenir l'entrée qui correspond tapez « comme étant » ; lorsque le résultat apparait cliquez le numéro dans la case « (comme étant)-ailleurs »  ; dans le nouveau cadre qui apparait, en haut à gauche cochez la case « paragraphe » puis cliquez « valider » ; la première tranche apparait alors à l'écran. (Pour les tranches suivantes entrer le numéro de sa première entrée puis cliquer « valider »)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for responding. You've reminded me of the verbs that take a subject complement. I consider that those form a different construction, and I've edited by question accordingly. The class of verbs "qui expriment une opinion, un jugement" might be the answer I'm seeking.

Comment: It's a pity that whoever marked LPH's answer down hasn't explained why. It might help me evaluate the response.

Comment: This answer seems correct to me. The possibility of this construction is very ad hoc: for eample it works with *croire*, but not with *penser*.